# Zend PDF word wrapping

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-pdf

Does Zend_Pdf already support automatic wrapping of text?

For example I want to create a textblock and fill it with text. This is a very important feature and unless Zend Pdf does not have it I am not able to switch from FPDF.

Also I think a Framework that says it has PDF support should be able to offer their developers this kind of feature.

Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed Zend_Pdf is not mature enough to compare with the regular Zend_YouNameIt component.

In my oppinion Zend_Pdf should not be part of Zend. It is very limited and can't be used in most cases because one or the other feature is missing.

As for the feature you are missing, you would have to check the Manual or read the code but in general I advise to use something else for PDF generation until Zend_Pdf is mature enough.

I think the best solution would be for Zend_Pdf to be a wrapper for some kind of command line tool.

Comment: Your answer might be old, but right now I think Zend_PDF has the basic set of function to handle 90 % of the case.

Answer (score 6):

couple of years later with Zend 1.11 this is working for me in a pdf class function

```
    /**
 * puts text box to a page
 * 
 * @param integer $offset_x
 * @param integer $offset_y
 */
public function drawTextArea($text, $pos_x, $pos_y, $height, $length = 0, $offset_x = 0, $offset_y = 0)        {
    $x = $pos_x + $offset_x;
    $y = $pos_y + $offset_y;);

    if ($length != 0) {
        $text = wordwrap($text, $length, "\n", false);
    }
    $token = strtok($text, "\n");

    while ($token != false) {
        $this->page->drawText($token, $x, $y);
        $token = strtok("\n");
        $y -= $height;
    }
}
```

if someone likes it use it

Answer (score 3):

Zend pdf is not supporting automatic word wrap.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you to use [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) instead. It allows you to define the page in html and render it into a pdf. Wordwrap will be handled fine!
It even allows for page breaks, so multi-page pdfs are possible.